# Remove trailing "US" and "CAN" strings from a range of cells

Tags: excel, substring, excel-formula

This is an example of the data in the column of the worksheet I have:

```
Mining US
Soybean Farming CAN
Soybean Farming
Oil Extraction US
Fishing
```

There are thousands of cells with string that end with " US" or " CAN" and what I need to do is take the " US" and " CAN" out of each cell that contains it.

the sub strings " US" and " CAN" are only present at the end of the string in cell if they are there at all. Some cells don't contain " US" or " CAN" but might end with the letters "us" or "can".

I would just like to remove these ending substrings so that my table would look like:

```
Mining
Soybean Farming
Soybean Farming
Oil Extraction
Fishing
```

I'm not very inexperienced with formulas and was wondering if someone could suggest a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can do a find and Replace or text To columns?

Comment: Some cells don't contain `" US"` or `" CAN"` but might end with the letters "us" or "can" -- and you DON'T want those cells touched. That wasn't totally clear to me and I had to re-read the question several times to get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, you can use Excel's inbuilt FIND for `" US"` and `" CAN"` and REPLACE them with Blanks. Remember to select the checkbox "Match Case". The Find and Replace can be invoked using the shortcut key <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> This is the most fastest way to achieve what you want.

**SNAPSHOT** on how to use FIND AND REPLACE FOR `" CAN"`. **Repeat for `" US"`**

[image]

But if you still want a formula then put this in `B1`

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" US",A1,1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND(" CAN",A1,1)),A1,LEFT(A1, FIND(" CAN",A1,1))),LEFT(A1, FIND(" US",A1,1)))`

I am assuming that the data is in Col A

Comment: @JimmyPena -> the op says that there are instances where `us` or `can` might appear at the end of a word, and he doesn't want them eliminated, just the `US` or `CAN`. Therefore this solution works perfectly.

Comment: @Scott I understand that now, deleting my comment shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a behemoth one line worksheet formula you can drag all the way down.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,LEN(" CAN"))=" CAN",TRIM(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(" CAN"))),IF(RIGHT(A1,LEN(" US"))=" US",TRIM(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(" US"))),A1))
```

Comment: will not work if the word is tuscan. Will take away the `can` and only leave `Tus` which OP says is not acceptable.

Comment: You're right. But adding a space in there fixes it (which I just did). Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

This will remove " US" or " CAN" from the end only

`=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4)&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,4)," US","")," CAN","")`

Note: SUBSTITUTE is case-sensitive

Comment: @JimmyPena -> the op says that there are instances where `us` or `can` might appear at the end of a word, and he doesn't want them eliminated, just the `US` or `CAN`.

Comment: @Scott My bad, I had to re-read the question a few times to understand that. Deleting my comment shortly.